# .net MVC page crashes for large data for Windows 8.1 + IE 11 combination

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, windows, internet-explorer-11

Our systems have been upgraded to Win 8.1 recently. Application which has been working fine on Windows 7+IE for same amount of data (2000 rows) now no longer loads in Windows 8.1 +IE 11. below are further details  of the issue :

a) Application is built on MVC 4 .Net.

b) The page which has loading issues now is expected to get a large amount (about 2000+ records which includes lot of calculations at various levels) of data to provide a "summary" feel of all the data and calculations.

c) This feature works fine on IE 11 + Win 7 combination.

d) In IE11 + Win8.1 combination the data is being fetched and is getting bound to the screen, but while rendering the page in required table structure, the IE hangs and goes into the "web page stopped responding" mode.

e) Jquery is being used to have a hide/show details on the page.

Please let me know if there is any specific solution to fix this.

below is the piece of the where we loop through the model object(containing about 2000 rows) and bind to the body. It uses partial views to bind the subtotal/total rows.The summed values are bound to the footer as final total.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        order = item.order;

        if (item.order == 0)
        {
            totalMaxFees += item.maxFee;
            totalEstFees += item.estimatedFee;
            totalComplete += item.complete;
            totalBaseHrs += item.baseHours;
            totalWipStd += item.totalWIP;
            totalAllowance += item.allowance;
            totalWipBase += item.netWIP;
            totalEstWipStd += item.additionalWIP;
            totalRecovery += item.recovery;
            totalCredits += item.credits;

        }
        else if (item.order == 1)
        {
            decimal ERVIndividual = 0;

            ERVIndividual = (item.totalWIP) * (item.recoveryPercent / 100);
            totalIncome += item.additionalIncome;
            ERVClient += ERVIndividual;
        }

        // examine the first letter of the client 
        // and group accordingly
        String letter = item.Mandate.Client.name.Substring(0, 1);
        letter = letter.ToUpper();

        try
        {
            int test = int.Parse(letter);
            letter = "0-9";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // can't cast it, so it's a letter
        }

        if (!letter.Equals(currentLetter))
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("ClientRollupHeader", letter);
            currentLetter = letter;
        }
        if (item.Mandate.Client.name != currentClient) {
            Html.RenderPartial("ClientGroupHeader", item);
            currentClient = item.Mandate.Client.name;
        }
        if (item.order == 1) {
            Html.RenderPartial("ClientTotalRow", item);
        } else {
            Html.RenderPartial("MandateTableRow", item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without code how is it possible to help/

Comment: hard to understand as it involves various render. The best I can recommend is there is something to do with either infinite loop or redirection loop through render partial. You will have to give it a go through debug steps.

Comment: The code works fine for smaller data, the page loads without IE crashing. So i am guessing it could possibly because of the large data rendering which causing browser issues only after we upgraded to Win 8.1.

Comment: I doubt honestly, 2000 records are not so high. Do you want to start from first 100 and then 200 and see where it break. You might be right, but that comes down do how heavy is your DOM. You cannot predict issue by number of records only.

Comment: Does the page work in different browsers?

Comment: yes it works fine in chrome. all the data renders fine and response to various click events is fine, post loading. i have checked in IE 10 on server 2012, it works fine here too. problem is only with IE 11 on Win 8.1

Comment: We have the same issue. Chrome and FF works perfectly. IE can't handle more than 200 records. Baffling. Limit the record count under that and everything is fine. Chrome and FF loads everything super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from "web page stopped responding" message, it indicates a problem with the JavaScript side rendering. It usually means that whatever your script is doing, is taking a long time. Eventually it crosses the timeout threshold for the browser leading the browser to think that the page has stopped responding.

Without looking further at the DOM side, its hard to pinpoint anything but here's some general debugging techniques:

- Does the same page work fine in Chrome or FF? If so, then it is surely a DOM rendering being slow issue. If no, then your server is taking too long to send results.
- You could [profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699341(v=vs.85).aspx) the page's script to see which method(s) is(are) taking longer. If IE profiling doesn't succeed due to page crash, try profiling in Chrome. Although different browsers have different JS engines, usually, they point towards the slowest function in same manner.
- Finally, if you still cannot figure out, then try introducing either paging, or rendering records in a batch (multiple ajax calls, each call fetching and appending n number of records). n or the sweet spot can be found via trial-n-error.

Further reading: See this [support base article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;175500) which tells you how IE determines when the JS has timed out:

> By default, the key does not exist. If the key has not been added, the default threshold limit for the time-out dialog box is 5,000,000 statements for Internet Explorer 4 and later versions.

It is also possible that you're going into recursion or some loop which also can cause the script to hang.

Comment: Yes in chrome the page works fine. Thank you for your inputs. will look further.